# Docker shell script not parameterizing as expected

Tags: bash, docker

I have the following `run.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" = build ]]
then
    python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
else
    echo "$1"
fi
```

And the following `Dockerfile` definition:

```
FROM python:3
COPY "app.py" /
COPY "requirements.txt" /
COPY "run.sh" /
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/run.sh"]
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT /run.sh
CMD build
```

`./run.sh foo` prints out `foo`, but `docker build . -t test; docker run test` prints an empty line. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the json/exec syntax for your CMD and ENTRYPOINT lines. Otherwise docker will wrap the commands with a shell:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
CMD ["build"]
```

See the [table in this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) for more details on how the two syntaxes interact.